# Intellij import issue - java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gradle

I am attempting to import a project from github into intellij and am running into this stack trace:

Caused by:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=2, No such file
>   or directory at
>   common_c6b3s0xd8gl4x9r47zsnga1nq$_run_closure12.doCall(/Users/jrengh/Documents/teri/common.gradle:97)

I have seen this issue posted around the internet a lot and the common solution seems to be to make sure that the git executable is correctly listed in the "Path to git executable" field under Settings > Version control > Git. I have done so, tested the connection and have gotten a successful message.

The issue stems from this task method called in a separate gradle file located within one of my project's dependencies:

## common.gradle

```
task buildInfo {
    def cmd = "git rev-parse --short HEAD"
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    project.ext.revision = proc.text.trim()
    cmd = "git show -s --format=%ct HEAD"
    proc = cmd.execute()
    project.ext.timestamp = proc.text.trim()
}
```

So essentially, intellij doesn't recognize the "git" in the command I try to execute above even though I have successfully uploaded a git executable. Does anyone have any helpful suggestions?

Comment: Chuck `git` into the user/system PATH?

Comment: I assume you mean add the git as a path variable?

Comment: Yes, outside of the IDE.

Comment: I attempted to do so by accessing Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment and adding the git path, but that did not have any effect.

Comment: I mean, set the PATH environment variable outside of the the IDE. This would then be inherited to all sub-processes, even if they ignore other path settings. It's a punt approach.

Comment: Ah I understand. Just tried it and unfortunately it did not work. Good idea though!

Comment: What is the output of command line execution of `git --version`?

Comment: OUTPUT: git version 1.8.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turned out, if I used the full directory location ('/usr/local/git/bin/git' in my case) instead of simply 'git' in those command executions, then the problem was solved. So for example, the first line of the method had to read "def proc = /usr/local/git/bin/git rev-parse --short HEAD".

If I were attempting to edit this code in a team setting (such as pushing it back into github for the other members of my team to see), then I would need to alias this directory location so that "git" could remain in the code and still work on my machine; however since I do not plan on pushing this back into github, this is all I need.

Comment: For my case changing `Version Control > Git > Path to Git executable` to the absolute path (you can get that through running `which git`) instead of just git did the trick

Answer (score 10):

I have just installed a fresh Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and Git was not installed.

On Ubuntu to install Git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

**Intellij Idea can of course not execute a command it does not find.**